# Can't read uploaded csv file in SageMaker Studio Lab anymore

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I used to use the pandas command: pd.read_csv('path copied from studio lab') to read the csv file
but now this same command seems to not work anymore. The path that I used in the pandas command I got by right-clicking on the upload filed and then selecting copy path.

Any help?

The error message:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Titanic/train.csv'

Comment: I'm facing the same problem;

Answer (score 0):

You can use boto3 to read the files

```
#pip install boto3

import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
obj = s3.get_object(
         Bucket = 'bucket_name',
         Key = 'path/to/file.csv'
      )
df = pd.read_csv(obj['Body'], nrows=100)
```

check few samples using `nrows` to make sure you see the data you were expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add `~/` in front of the file path

```
df = pd.read_csv("~/data/sagemaker_sample.csv")
```

instead of

```
df = pd.read_csv("data/sagemaker_sample.csv")
```